# Event Sourcing - How to query inside a command?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

We would like to be able to read state inside a command use case.

We could get the state from event store for the specific aggregate, but what about querying aggregates by field(not id) or performing more complicated queries, that are not fitted for the event store?

The approach we were thinking was to use our read model for those cases as well and not only for query use cases.

This might be inconsistent, so a solution could be to have the latest version of the aggregate stored in both write/read models, in order to be able to tell if the state is correct or stale.

Does this make sense and if yes, if we need to get state by Id should we use event store or the read model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the absolute latest state of an event-sourced aggregate, you're going to have to read the latest snapshot (assuming that you are snapshotting) and then replay events since that snapshot from the event store.  You can be aggressive about snapshotting (conceivably even saving a snapshot after every command), but you're giving away some write performance to make the read faster.

Updating the read model directly is conceivably possible, though that level of coupling is something that should be considered very carefully.  Note also that you will very likely need some sort of two-phase commit to ensure that the read model is only updated when the write model is updated and vice versa.  I strongly suggest considering why you're using CQRS/ES in this project, because you are quite possibly undermining that reason by doing this sort of thing.

In general, if you need a query for processing a particular command, it's likely that query will generally be the same, i.e. you don't need free-form query support.  In that case, you can often have a read model that's tuned for exactly that query and which only cares about events which could affect that query: often a fairly small subset of the events.  The finer-grained the read model, the easier it is to keep in sync (if it ignores 99% of events, for instance, it can't really fall that far behind).

Needing to make complex queries as part of command processing could also be a sign that your aggregate boundaries aren't right and could do with a re-examination.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! So, you suggest to have predefined read models for every query we might need in a command, right?If we wanted to add a new one, should we replay all the related events up to this point?

Comment: Also, should we have transactions for updating all the read models?

Comment: The read models themselves can definitely be transactional.  But putting "update read models" into the same transaction as updating the write model tends to work against the reasons to do CQRS (for instance, different scaling requirements).

Comment: For building a new read model, yes, you may well have to replay all events.  There are definitely conceivable read models where you wouldn't have to (for instance: net change in some value this calendar month).

Comment: "In that case, you can often have a read model that's tuned for exactly that query" from this I suppose you meant read model for commands, which is in event store and different than the actual read model that could be perhaps in a different DB. So I meant transaction between the event store read and write model. e.g. save User events in write model by id,email,username etc.

Comment: There's no such thing as a read model for commands beyond the trivial one which is (in an ES write-model) replaying the events for a particular aggregate in some time.  Read models don't intrinsically require any storage.

Comment: By "read model tuned exactly for that query" I mean, for instance, say you have an order aggregate.  You need to answer the question "value of checked out orders for a given customer with a special discount code".  Then you can have a read model that updates on, for instance, `DiscountCodeApplied`, `CustomerInfoAdded`, and `CheckedOut` events (ignoring the other events associated with an order), keeping a table mapping a customer x discount code to a total value.

Comment: Ok now I see what you meant and it's a great solution for multiple read models. Although, in cases where you absolutely need consistency in a query when handling a command is there a way you can do that with event sourcing?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this make sense

Maybe.  Let's start with

> This might be inconsistent

Yup, they might be.  So what?

We typically respond to a query by sending an unlocked copy of the answer.  In other words, it's possible that the actual information in the write model will change after this response is dispatched but before the response arrives at its destination.  The client will be looking at a copy of the answer taken from the past.

So we might reasonably ask how much better it is to get information no more than one minute old compared to information no more than five minutes old.  If the difference in value is pennies, then you should probably deploy the five minute version.  If the difference is millions of dollars, then you're in a good position to negotiate a real budget to solve the problem.

For processing a command in our own write model, that kind of inconsistency isn't usually acceptable or wise.  But neither of the two common answers require keeping the read and write models synchronized.  The most common answer is to just work with the write model alone.  The less common answer is to grab a snapshot out of a cache, and *then apply any additional events to it* to bring it up to date.  The latter approach is "just" a performance optimization (first rule: don't.)

The variation that trips everyone up is trying to process a command somewhere else, enforcing a consistency rule on our data here.  Once again, you need a really clear picture of how valuable the consistency is to the business.  If it's really important, that may be a signal that the information in question shouldn't be split into two different piles - you may be working with the wrong underlying data model.

Possibly useful references

- Pat Helland [Data on the Outside Versus Data on the Inside](https://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf)
- Udi Dahan [Race Conditions Don't Exist](https://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure I get what the variation is. 
If consistency is important for the business, you would have read models for command in the event store that you would update transactionally?